# DJANGO + windows: .bat file: open a command prompt and run the commands

Tags: python, django, windows

I have to run the following set of commands after opening a windows cmd prompt

```
D:
cd Dev\project\backend
.\venv\Scripts\activate
python manage.py runserver
```

How to write a script(.bat) file for running these commands and the runserver will stay showing the output

I tried to put these commands in django.bat and double click, but a cmd window opens and within a fraction of second it closes. Dont know what happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do this recently, but had to move onto something else quickly; given your question it's a nice opportunity to return to it, and I believe I've found the answer!

From what I found on my Laptop just now, the issue is with the **activate** line

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

On Windows, this is another **.bat** file, and I suspect that calling it runs in a new **cmd** instance, rather than the current one

So I simply copied the entire contents of **activate.bat** and put it into my custom script, and it worked!

```
@echo off
cd D:\Dev\project\backend
-> Paste entire contents of activate.bat on this line <-
.\manage.py runserver
```

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi - this should definitely work, as I did it prior to writing my response. If all is well, kindly mark the answer as accepted. If not, let me know the error and I'll try to assist

Answer (score 1):

Instead of activating the venv then running `manage.py` separately, you should run directly using the `python.exe` from your virtual env.

It should look like this:
`> D:\Dev\project\backend\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\Dev\project\backend\manage.py runserver`

I don't really know what you intent to use this for, but in windows you should run your Django project using IIS. Check out `django-windowsauth`, you can use it to run Django on IIS in few commands. https://github.com/danyi1212/django-windowsauth.
Just skip adding the middleware and the authentication backend of you don't need Windows Authentication on your site.